# error conectando a un Datasource en weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic

Tengo una Datasource creado en Weblogic pero cuando lo invoco desde una clase, me genera el error :

> javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/ConexionFV' in
>   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.provider.url=t3://127.0.0.1:7001,
>   java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root
>   exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ConexionFV not found]

Si alguien me puede guiar para entender que estoy haciendo mal, les agradecería mucho la ayuda...este es mi código.

```
    private static InitialContext ctx = null;
//public static InitialContext getInitialContext( ) throws NamingException {
public static synchronized Connection getConexion() {
   Context ctx = null;
   Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
   ht.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
   ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"t3://127.0.0.1:7001");//hostname:port");
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   try {
     ctx = new InitialContext(ht);
     javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup ("jdbc/ConexionFV");
     conn = ds.getConnection();
   }catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Error --> " + e);
     conn = null;
   }
   return conn;
}
```

Comment: Mckimley, he agregado una respuesta, sería interesante agregaras tu archivo weblogic.properties , pero seguramente el problema es el nombre del DS.

Answer (score 1):

Regularmente este error

> javax.naming.**NamingException**: Lookup failed for 'jdbc/ConexionFV' in
>   SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.provider.url=t3://127.0.0.1:7001,
>   java.naming.factory.initial=weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory,
>   java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl,
>   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root
>   exception is **javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: ConexionFV not found**]

es causado porque existe un error  al escribir el nombre correcto del Data Source o no esta especificado.

Revisa en tu archivo `weblogic.properties` **el nombre del Data Source, al parecer `ConexionFV` no es correcto**:

```
 javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup ("jdbc/ConexionFV");
```

Comment: Pero cuando entro a la Consola, es el Datasource correcto, de hecho lo cree yo mismo y la conexión fue exitosa....tambien probe cambiando el Host por "localhost" y genera el mismo error...que puedo revisar.

Comment: Una letra más o menos? ya que indica que no encuentra "ConexionFV".

Comment: La he copiado...y pegado no tiene espacios en blanco...no hay alguna forma de probar algo???...como para indagar en que parte hay un corto circuito?

Comment: Me comentas que probaste la conexión por lo cual es muy raro este problema, podrías agregar lo que puedas de tu  weblogic.properties

Comment: Eleanasys, pues el Datasource lo cree con el nombre ConexionFV el jndi se llama jdbc/ConexionFV, en el pool de conexiones la url es jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.1.1.197:1521:bdV1, nombre del controlador : oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource, nombre del servidor AdminServer y el estado esta en RUNNING..en fin...por eso escribi la pregunta, no se que mirar y ya he leido toda la documentacion de WEGLOGIC...

Comment: como reviso el weblogic.properties, he vuelto a retomar este problema en mi aplicacion, y he estado leyendo pero aun no consigo conectarme atravez del Datasource, por hay tambien he leido que la aplicacion debe estar en el mismo servidor...pero tampoco funciona. Agradezco tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a cambiar el nombre Datasource por algo diferente al jndi. Es decir, si tu jndi es "jdbc/ConexionFV", el Datasource debería ser diferente a ConexionFV, por ejemplo si es un DB2 la BBDD, DB2conexionFV con jndi "jdbc/ConexinoFV".

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta de una cosa. Si te fijas en el error que arroja, se está invocando el admin server via t3. Borra el datasource, vuelvelo a generar y asegurate que el protocolo que utilizas no es t3 sino http, por ejemplo. Prueba y me comentas.